# avoid overwriting of file and content with each run or request with executable directory

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, exe, executable

Hello I’m trying to create directory folder with text document for my windows form application executable. Now I must make it available  locally for other users.

I'm doing it this way:

```
 string dir = "%ProgramData%\\MyAppName\\doc.txt";
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir));
            var stream = File.CreateText(dir);            
            stream.Close();
        }
```

and here is my access path from executable directory inside the code:

```
const string mypath = (@"%ProgramData%\MyAppName\doc.txt");
```

On the one stage of implementation I have also separate creation of document, but I almost  sure  that  has no connection with problem, because  creates it once and never overwrites if file exist, keeps content of text document with each new run of program, adding of data or request to it. Only if I delete it by hand, in this case creates new one:

```
if (File.Exists(mypath))
                wordsTyped.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(mypath));
```

and works perfect with local path to debug folder like this:

```
const string tetdb = ("doc.txt");
```

So code for executable must work same way, if directory, folder, file with content exist don't do nothing with it. But with code above, it rewrites everything  with every request to it, not only with new run of program, with folder, text document and content inside.

but must be as follows: if folder is created once, if directory, file, document exist, no netter with code of executable, or with press enter, or it was already there. keep content inside the text document  with every start of program or request to it of adding to it.

I've tried create only folder to executable path, to create text document separately as it shown above, but I got same result. So how to avoid this problem, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"%ProgramData%\\MyAppName\\doc.txt";` is the file name not dir name. So `Directory.Exists(dir)` will always fail...(Compare it with `File.Exists`)

Comment: Code in the post makes no sense - why one would create folder and then immediately try to open it as text file? Please post code that at least looks reasonable. Side note: on normal system where users don't have admin permissions your code will not be able to write to app data folder at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test for `!Directory.Exists` is the cause of your problem.
You pass a filename to the method, thus the method returns false (a directory with that name doesn't exist). 
This means that you always enter the if and calling [File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx) over an existing file overwrite the content of the file

```
string file = "%ProgramData%\\MyAppName\\doc.txt";
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)))
{
   ....
}
```